# System environment variable created during install not available to current user until reboot

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, environment-variables

I have a msi package generated by wix that creates a system environment variable by populating the [`Environment` table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368369(VS.85).aspx).

```
<Environment Id="CreateEnvVar" Name="DATADIR" Action="set"
        System="yes" Part="all" Value="[DATA_DIR]" />
```

The install successfully creates the environment variable at the system level.  This was verified by viewing the `Environment Variables` dialog from `System Properties`

However the currently logged in user does not have access to the newly created environment variables until the machine is rebooted ( I'm assuming that logging out then back in would also work.  Just have not tried it yet).  Executing an application that was just installed fails because it does not have access to the `DATADIR` variable.

Also, opening up a command prompt after the installation is complete the `DATADIR` variable does not appear when executing the `set` command.

I understand that a process started before executing the MSI would not get the new variables.  However, why wouldn't a process started after the environment variables are added get the new ones?

FYI, I am installing on Windows Server 2003 and I am logged in through remote desktop with a user in the `Administrators` group.

Comment: We verified that logging out and logging back in (through remote desktop) does refresh the environment variables for the user.

Also, by taking remote desktop out of the equation and logging directly into the console of the machine we are able to get access to the new variables with out having to log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you installing via Remote Desktop? If so, ensure you are using the admin console session.

To do so, launch Remote Desktop using:

> mstsc /admin

Or if you are using the latest version of RDP, it is now:

> mstsc /console

Try installing it from this session (or locally) and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That ended up being the problem.  And we were having problems with the /admin /console.  Originally we were connecting as /console but apparently that's been deprecated in later releases.